# How to derive the formula of the sum of this finite series: $\sum_{n=M}^N a^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I would like to know how to arrive at the following result that
my teacher wrote on the board. They did not explain how it was done. I am also not sure what this series is called. Is it perhaps a power series?

> $$N>M :\sum_{n=M}^N a^n = \frac{a^M-a^{N+1}}{1-a},a\neq1$$
> $$N>M: \sum_{n=M}^N a^n = N-M+1,a=1$$

I am quite lost since my teacher only wrote the above formulae without any derivation. Can someone help me understand why they are true? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like an application of geometric series, i.e. $\sum_{i=0}^n a^i = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$.

Comment: geometric series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one can be derived by the [**geometric series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

$$\sum_{n=M}^N a^n =\sum_{n=0}^N a^n-\sum_{n=0}^{M-1} a^n  $$

the second one is simply

$$\sum_{n=M}^N 1 $$

Comment: but you wrote from 0 to N i dont think its the same, sum of series for exm. from 5 till 8 its not like from 0 to 5 minus series from 0 to 7.

Comment: @DvirIhie But form $5$ to $8$ is like $0$ to $8$ minus $0$ to $4$, that's what I wrote.

Comment: oh my bad thank you !!!

Comment: @DvirIhie You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

Let us define

$$
\begin{align}
s_n = \sum_{n = M}^{N} a^n = a^M + a^{M+1} + \cdots + a^N.
\end{align}
\tag{1}
$$

Hence
$$
\begin{align}
a s_n = a^{M+1} + a^{M+2} + \cdots + a^{N+1}
\end{align}.
\tag{2}
$$

By subtracting (2) from (1), we get
$$
\begin{align}
s_n - a s_n = a^{M} - a^{N+1}
\end{align}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
s_n = \sum_{n = M}^{N} a^n = \frac{a^{M} - a^{N+1}}{1- a} & \text{,  for } a\neq 1
\end{align}
$$

The solution when $a=1$ is trivial:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = M}^{N} 1^n = \sum_{n = M}^{N} 1 = M-N+1
\end{align},
$$